# Regular expression to combine general cleanup with specific scenarios

Tags: python

I have a regex that performs unicode cleanup;

`re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', string)`

How do I add specific additional regex's in addition to the above?

EDIT: Clarified scenario:
I am using the regex in an API call to find specific keywords. But some of the keywords could be spelled in different ways.

For example, if I want to call the API to find mentions of coca-cola. It could be spelled as "coca-cola", or "Coca Cola", or "cocacola".

I have a list of keywords that I feed the api. But in above example I only want to feed it one value: "cocacola" and have it find all the permutations.
In addition I want it to perform the `[^\w\s]` cleanup too.

I do not want to just remove all whitespace as the API scrapes through a lot of data. So for example I do not want a regex that removes all spaces to see if the result is "cocacola". I would rather feed it specific scenarios.

Comment: Do this as a separate step before or after the general cleanup. Don't try to do it all in a single regexp.

Comment: Are you referring to just the classic _white-space_ from the _ASCII_ set, or the newer, "white-space" within Unicode?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub(r'[^\w\s]| ', '', string)`?